# Logstash shutdown recurrenctly in docker-container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, logstash-configuration, elasticsearch-7

I have used docker-compose to run ELKB. My primary goal is to starting elasticsearch and logstash containers. Logstash container should successfully be connected with elasticsearch and pass the logs to elasticsearch for further searching or processing.

But unknowingly reason logstash container should stop frequently. I need to persist in the logstash and elasticsearch container but it does not happen.

I don't know what is the reason to shut down the logstash container recurrently.

I use elasticsearch:7.6.3 and logstash:7.6.3

Please review the below code and guide me where I made a mistake.

> **docker-compose.yml**

```
# Docker version 19.03.5
# docker-compose version 1.25.3
version: "3.7"
services:
  elasticsearch:
    container_name: elasticsearch
    build:
      context: ./elasticsearch
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
      - 9300:9300
    volumes:
      - ./elasticsearch/data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data:rw
      - ./elasticsearch/logs:/usr/share/elasticsearch/logs:rw
    restart: always
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    networks:
      - elkb
  logstash:
    container_name: logstash
    build:
      context: ./logstash
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 9600:9600
      - 5000:5000/udp
      - 5000:5000/tcp
    volumes:
      - ./logstash/input-logs:/usr/share/logstash/logs
      - ./logstash/data:/var/lib/logstash:rw
      - ./logstash/logs:/var/logs/logstash:rw
    restart: always
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    networks:
      - elkb
    links:
      - elasticsearch
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch

networks:
  elk:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  elasticsearch:
```

> **Elasticsearch Dockerfile**

```
FROM docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.6.2
/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml
RUN mkdir -p /var/log/elasticsearch
RUN chown -R elasticsearch:elasticsearch /var/log/elasticsearch
RUN mkdir -p /var/lib/elasticsearch
RUN chown -R elasticsearch:elasticsearch /var/lib/elasticsearch
EXPOSE 9200
EXPOSE 9300
```

> **elasticsearch.yml**

```
cluster.name: es_cluster
node.name: es_node_1
bootstrap.memory_lock: true
network.host: 0.0.0.0
http.port: 9200
discovery.seed_hosts: ["0.0.0.0"]
cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["es_node_1"]
```

> **Logstash Dockerfile**

```
FROM docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash:7.6.2
COPY logstash.yml /usr/share/logstash/config/logstash.yml
COPY ./pipeline/logstash.conf /usr/share/logstash/pipeline/logstash.conf
EXPOSE 9600
```

> **logstash.yml**

```
http.host: "0.0.0.0"
xpack.monitoring.elasticsearch.hosts: "http://elasticsearch:9200"
xpack.monitoring.enabled: true
```

> **logstash.conf**

```
input{
  stdin{}
}
output{
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["http://elasticsearch:9200"]
  }
}
```

> **Container logs of logstash**

```
container_logstash    | WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
container_logstash    | WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.headius.backport9.modules.Modules (file:/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/jars/jruby-complete-9.2.9.0.jar) to method sun.nio.ch.NativeThread.signal(long)
container_logstash    | WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.headius.backport9.modules.Modules
container_logstash    | WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
container_logstash    | WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
container_logstash    | Sending Logstash logs to /usr/share/logstash/logs which is now configured via log4j2.properties
container_logstash    | [2020-04-25T14:50:33,271][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Starting Logstash {"logstash.version"=>"7.6.2"}
container_logstash    | [2020-04-25T14:50:34,013][INFO ][logstash.licensechecker.licensereader] Elasticsearch pool URLs updated {:changes=>{:removed=>[], :added=>[http://elasticsearch:9200/]}}
container_logstash    | [2020-04-25T14:50:34,127][WARN ][logstash.licensechecker.licensereader] Restored connection to ES instance {:url=>"http://elasticsearch:9200/"}
container_logstash    | [2020-04-25T14:50:34,157][INFO ][logstash.licensechecker.licensereader] ES Output version determined {:es_version=>7}
container_logstash    | [2020-04-25T14:50:34,160][WARN ][logstash.licensechecker.licensereader] Detected a 6.x and above cluster: the `type` event field won't be used to determine the document _type {:es_version=>7}
container_logstash    | [2020-04-25T14:50:34,243][INFO ][logstash.monitoring.internalpipelinesource] Monitoring License OK
container_logstash    | [2020-04-25T14:50:34,244][INFO ][logstash.monitoring.internalpipelinesource] Validated license for monitoring. Enabling monitoring pipeline.
container_logstash    | [2020-04-25T14:50:34,982][INFO ][org.reflections.Reflections] Reflections took 22 ms to scan 1 urls, producing 20 keys and 40 values 
container_logstash    | [2020-04-25T14:50:35,126][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Elasticsearch pool URLs updated {:changes=>{:removed=>[], :added=>[http://elasticsearch:9200/]}}
container_logstash    | [2020-04-25T14:50:35,134][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Restored connection to ES instance {:url=>"http://elasticsearch:9200/"}
container_logstash    | [2020-04-25T14:50:35,138][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] ES Output version determined {:es_version=>7}
container_logstash    | [2020-04-25T14:50:35,138][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Detected a 6.x and above cluster: the `type` event field won't be used to determine the document _type {:es_version=>7}
container_logstash    | [2020-04-25T14:50:35,159][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] New Elasticsearch output {:class=>"LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch", :hosts=>["http://elasticsearch:9200"]}
container_logstash    | [2020-04-25T14:50:35,182][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Using default mapping template
container_logstash    | [2020-04-25T14:50:35,206][WARN ][org.logstash.instrument.metrics.gauge.LazyDelegatingGauge][main] A gauge metric of an unknown type (org.jruby.specialized.RubyArrayOneObject) has been created for key: cluster_uuids. This may result in invalid serialization.  It is recommended to log an issue to the responsible developer/development team.
container_logstash    | [2020-04-25T14:50:35,213][INFO ][logstash.javapipeline    ][main] Starting pipeline {:pipeline_id=>"main", "pipeline.workers"=>6, "pipeline.batch.size"=>125, "pipeline.batch.delay"=>50, "pipeline.max_inflight"=>750, "pipeline.sources"=>["/usr/share/logstash/pipeline/logstash.conf"], :thread=>"#<Thread:0x27747a5a run>"}
container_logstash    | [2020-04-25T14:50:35,213][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Attempting to install template {:manage_template=>{"index_patterns"=>"logstash-*", "version"=>60001, "settings"=>{"index.refresh_interval"=>"5s", "number_of_shards"=>1, "index.lifecycle.name"=>"logstash-policy", "index.lifecycle.rollover_alias"=>"logstash"}, "mappings"=>{"dynamic_templates"=>[{"message_field"=>{"path_match"=>"message", "match_mapping_type"=>"string", "mapping"=>{"type"=>"text", "norms"=>false}}}, {"string_fields"=>{"match"=>"*", "match_mapping_type"=>"string", "mapping"=>{"type"=>"text", "norms"=>false, "fields"=>{"keyword"=>{"type"=>"keyword", "ignore_above"=>256}}}}}], "properties"=>{"@timestamp"=>{"type"=>"date"}, "@version"=>{"type"=>"keyword"}, "geoip"=>{"dynamic"=>true, "properties"=>{"ip"=>{"type"=>"ip"}, "location"=>{"type"=>"geo_point"}, "latitude"=>{"type"=>"half_float"}, "longitude"=>{"type"=>"half_float"}}}}}}}
container_logstash    | [2020-04-25T14:50:35,711][INFO ][logstash.javapipeline    ][main] Pipeline started {"pipeline.id"=>"main"}
container_logstash    | [2020-04-25T14:50:35,738][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Pipelines running {:count=>1, :running_pipelines=>[:main], :non_running_pipelines=>[]}
container_logstash    | [2020-04-25T14:50:36,233][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] You are using a deprecated config setting "document_type" set in elasticsearch. Deprecated settings will continue to work, but are scheduled for removal from logstash in the future. Document types are being deprecated in Elasticsearch 6.0, and removed entirely in 7.0. You should avoid this feature If you have any questions about this, please visit the #logstash channel on freenode irc. {:name=>"document_type", :plugin=><LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch bulk_path=>"/_monitoring/bulk?system_id=logstash&system_api_version=7&interval=1s", hosts=>[http://elasticsearch:9200], sniffing=>false, manage_template=>false, id=>"ebdd88635541942b096027ed79be84efc3dd562a5f0e1b78fca83c7b5c9a1a7c", document_type=>"%{[@metadata][document_type]}", enable_metric=>true, codec=><LogStash::Codecs::Plain id=>"plain_031a6e38-cafd-42f9-b689-b577ba9acc88", enable_metric=>true, charset=>"UTF-8">, workers=>1, template_name=>"logstash", template_overwrite=>false, doc_as_upsert=>false, script_type=>"inline", script_lang=>"painless", script_var_name=>"event", scripted_upsert=>false, retry_initial_interval=>2, retry_max_interval=>64, retry_on_conflict=>1, ilm_enabled=>"auto", ilm_rollover_alias=>"logstash", ilm_pattern=>"{now/d}-000001", ilm_policy=>"logstash-policy", action=>"index", ssl_certificate_verification=>true, sniffing_delay=>5, timeout=>60, pool_max=>1000, pool_max_per_route=>100, resurrect_delay=>5, validate_after_inactivity=>10000, http_compression=>false>}
container_logstash    | [2020-04-25T14:50:36,246][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][.monitoring-logstash] Elasticsearch pool URLs updated {:changes=>{:removed=>[], :added=>[http://elasticsearch:9200/]}}
container_logstash    | [2020-04-25T14:50:36,250][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][.monitoring-logstash] Restored connection to ES instance {:url=>"http://elasticsearch:9200/"}
container_logstash    | [2020-04-25T14:50:36,253][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][.monitoring-logstash] ES Output version determined {:es_version=>7}
container_logstash    | [2020-04-25T14:50:36,253][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][.monitoring-logstash] Detected a 6.x and above cluster: the `type` event field won't be used to determine the document _type {:es_version=>7}
container_logstash    | [2020-04-25T14:50:36,268][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][.monitoring-logstash] New Elasticsearch output {:class=>"LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch", :hosts=>["http://elasticsearch:9200"]}
container_logstash    | [2020-04-25T14:50:36,271][INFO ][logstash.javapipeline    ][.monitoring-logstash] Starting pipeline {:pipeline_id=>".monitoring-logstash", "pipeline.workers"=>1, "pipeline.batch.size"=>2, "pipeline.batch.delay"=>50, "pipeline.max_inflight"=>2, "pipeline.sources"=>["monitoring pipeline"], :thread=>"#<Thread:0x6e9553e7 run>"}
container_logstash    | [2020-04-25T14:50:36,288][INFO ][logstash.javapipeline    ][.monitoring-logstash] Pipeline started {"pipeline.id"=>".monitoring-logstash"}
container_logstash    | [2020-04-25T14:50:36,294][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Pipelines running {:count=>1, :running_pipelines=>[:".monitoring-logstash"], :non_running_pipelines=>[:main]}
container_logstash    | [2020-04-25T14:50:36,398][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}
container_logstash    | [2020-04-25T14:50:37,402][INFO ][logstash.javapipeline    ] Pipeline terminated {"pipeline.id"=>".monitoring-logstash"}
container_logstash    | [2020-04-25T14:50:38,337][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Logstash shut down.
```

Please let me know if you need more clarification or need more information.

Thank you for the resolution.

Comment: do u solved the problem?

Comment: Yes I have solved it.

Comment: ...then please put it as an aswer to your question.

Comment: @bellackn Ok give me today I will post the answer.

Comment: @Dipakchavda please share your solution as i also have the same trouble and can't find out what is wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**@wobmene** **@bellackn** Sorry for the delayed answer to the above question which I had asked a long back.

To resolve the above issues, I have reconfigured ELKB with the following configuration. There might be possible that I am not giving you a full qualified justification of the above answer, but I tried my best.

**quinn** is the name I used for this build and services.

> ELKB Repository structure

```
elkb
    - elasticsearch
        Dockerfile
        elasticsearch.yml
    - filebeat
        Dockerfile
        filebeat.yml
    - kibana
        Dockerfile
        kibana.yml
    - logstash
        - pipeline
            logstash.conf
        Dockerfile
        logstash.yml
    docker-compose.yml
```

> ELKB ports

```
 - elasticsearch: 9200/9300  
 - logstash: 9600  
 - kibana: 5601  
 - filbeats: 5044
```

> elkb/docker-compose.yml

```
# Docker version 19.03.5
# docker-compose version 1.25.3

version: "3.7"
services:
  elasticsearch:
    container_name: elasticsearch
    build:
      context: ./elasticsearch
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
      - 9300:9300
    volumes:
      - ./elasticsearch/data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data:rw
      - ./elasticsearch/logs:/usr/share/elasticsearch/logs:rw
    restart: always
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    networks:
      - quinn_elkb

  quinn_logstash:
    container_name: quinn_logstash
    build:
      context: ./logstash
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 9600:9600
      - 5000:5000/udp
      - 5000:5000/tcp
    volumes:
      - ./logstash/input-logs:/usr/share/logstash/logs
      - ./logstash/data:/var/lib/logstash:rw
      - ./logstash/logs:/var/logs/logstash:rw
    restart: always
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    networks:
      - quinn_elkb
    links:
      - elasticsearch
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch

  quinn_kibana:
    container_name: quinn_kibana
    build:
      context: ./kibana
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 5601:5601
    restart: always
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    networks:
      - quinn_elkb
    links:
      - elasticsearch
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch

  quinn_filebeat:
    container_name: quinn_filebeat
    build:
      context: ./filebeat
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 5044:5044
    volumes:
      - ./../logs:/input-logs
    restart: always
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    networks:
      - quinn_elkb
    links:
      - elasticsearch
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch

networks:
  quinn_elkb:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  elasticsearch:
    driver: local
```

> elkb/elasticsearch/Dockerfile

```
FROM docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.6.2
COPY ./elasticsearch.yml /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml
RUN mkdir -p /var/log/elasticsearch
RUN chown -R elasticsearch:elasticsearch /var/log/elasticsearch
RUN mkdir -p /var/lib/elasticsearch
RUN chown -R elasticsearch:elasticsearch /var/lib/elasticsearch
EXPOSE 9200
EXPOSE 9300
```

> elkb/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml

```
# ======================== Elasticsearch Configuration =========================
#
# NOTE: Elasticsearch comes with reasonable defaults for most settings.
#       Before you set out to tweak and tune the configuration, make sure you
#       understand what are you trying to accomplish and the consequences.
#
# The primary way of configuring a node is via this file. This template lists
# the most important settings you may want to configure for a production cluster.
#
# Please consult the documentation for further information on configuration options:
# https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/index.html
#
# ---------------------------------- Cluster -----------------------------------
#
# Use a descriptive name for your cluster:
#
cluster.name: quinn_es_cluster
#
# ------------------------------------ Node ------------------------------------
#
# Use a descriptive name for the node:
#
node.name: quinn_es_node_1
#
# Add custom attributes to the node:
#
#node.attr.rack: r1
#
# ----------------------------------- Paths ------------------------------------
#
# Path to directory where to store the data (separate multiple locations by comma):
#
# ${path.data}
#
# Path to log files:
#
# ${path.logs}
#
# ----------------------------------- Memory -----------------------------------
#
# Lock the memory on startup:
#
bootstrap.memory_lock: true
#
# Make sure that the heap size is set to about half the memory available
# on the system and that the owner of the process is allowed to use this
# limit.
#
# Elasticsearch performs poorly when the system is swapping the memory.
#
# ---------------------------------- Network -----------------------------------
#
# Set the bind address to a specific IP (IPv4 or IPv6):
#
network.host: 0.0.0.0
#
# Set a custom port for HTTP:
#
http.port: 9200
#
# For more information, consult the network module documentation.
#
# --------------------------------- Discovery ----------------------------------
#
# Pass an initial list of hosts to perform discovery when this node is started:
# The default list of hosts is ["127.0.0.1", "[::1]"]
#
# discovery.seed_hosts: ["127.0.0.1", "[::1]", "0.0.0.0"]
discovery.seed_hosts: ["0.0.0.0"]
#
# Bootstrap the cluster using an initial set of master-eligible nodes:
#
cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["quinn_es_node_1"]
#
# For more information, consult the discovery and cluster formation module documentation.
#
# ---------------------------------- Gateway -----------------------------------
#
# Block initial recovery after a full cluster restart until N nodes are started:
#
#gateway.recover_after_nodes: 3
#
# For more information, consult the gateway module documentation.
#
# ---------------------------------- Various -----------------------------------
#
# Require explicit names when deleting indices:
#
#action.destructive_requires_name: true
```

> elkb/filebeat/Dockerfile

```
FROM docker.elastic.co/beats/filebeat:7.6.2
COPY filebeat.yml /usr/share/filebeat/filebeat.yml
USER root
RUN mkdir -p /input-logs/
# RUN chown root:filebeat /usr/share/filebeat/filebeat.yml
RUN chmod go-w /usr/share/filebeat/filebeat.yml
USER filebeat
EXPOSE 5044
```

> elkb/filebeat/filebeat.yml

```
filebeat.inputs:
  - type: log
    enabled: true
    paths:
      # here is the reference of docker directory.
      # The current directory of docker is /usr/share/filebeat
      - ../../../input-logs/**/*.log

processors:
  - add_docker_metadata: ~

reload.enabled: true
reload.period: 10s

output.logstash:
  hosts: ["quinn_logstash:5044"]

logging.json: true
logging.metrics.enabled: false
```

> elkb/kibana/Dockerfile

```
FROM docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:7.6.2
COPY ./kibana.yml /usr/share/kibana/config/kibana.yml
EXPOSE 5601
```

> elkb/kibana/kibana.yml

```
server.name: quinn_kibana
server.host: "0.0.0.0"
elasticsearch.hosts: ["http://elasticsearch:9200"]
xpack.monitoring.ui.container.elasticsearch.enabled: true
## X-Pack security credentials
# elasticsearch.username: elastic
# elasticsearch.password: changeme
```

> elkb/logstash/pipeline/logstash.conf

```
input {
  beats {
    port => 5044
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => "elasticsearch:9200"
    index => "%{[@metadata][beat]}-%{[@metadata][version]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
  }
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

> elkb/logstash/Dockerfile

```
FROM docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash:7.6.2
COPY ./logstash.yml /usr/share/logstash/config/logstash.yml
COPY ./pipeline/logstash.conf /usr/share/logstash/pipeline/logstash.conf
EXPOSE 9600
```

> elkb/logstash/logstash.yml

```
http.host: "0.0.0.0"
xpack.monitoring.elasticsearch.hosts: "http://elasticsearch:9200"
xpack.monitoring.enabled: true
# xpack.monitoring.elasticsearch.username: elastic
# xpack.monitoring.elasticsearch.password: changeme
```

I have read the following articles; all have an excellent reference that helps to resolve the above issues and configure the ELKB.

https://medium.com/@sece.cosmin/docker-logs-with-elastic-stack-elk-filebeat-50e2b20a27c6
https://github.com/cosminseceleanu/tutorials
https://elk-docker.readthedocs.io/#prerequisites
https://github.com/elastic/stack-docker/blob/master/docker-compose.yml
https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/distribution/docker/docker-compose.yml
http://cambio.name/index.php/node/522